# Add name to array using jersey

Tags: java, json, jersey

I am implementing an example [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Google-App-Engine-Java)

I need the output json to name the array.

`{"files":[]}` instead of just `{[]}` which is what I'm currently getting as output.  What do I need to do to add a name to the array?

```
 @GET
 @Path("/{key}/meta")
public Response redirect(@PathParam("key") String key) throws IOException {
BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(key);
BlobInfo info = blobInfoFactory.loadBlobInfo(blobKey);

String name = info.getFilename();
long size = info.getSize();
String url = "/rest/file/" + key; 
FileMeta meta = new FileMeta(name, size, url);

List<FileMeta> metas = Lists.newArrayList(meta);
GenericEntity<List<FileMeta>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<FileMeta>>(metas) {};
return Response.ok(entity).build();
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your Entity Class to contain an instance of `List<FileMeta>` called `files` to have that JSON Output.

```
public Class EntityClass
{
  private List<FileMeta> files;
  //Getter and Setter Methods.
}
```

Here's what you need to have in `redirect` method.

```
@GET
@Path("/{key}/meta")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response redirect(@PathParam("key") String key) throws IOException {
BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(key);
BlobInfo info = blobInfoFactory.loadBlobInfo(blobKey);

String name = info.getFilename();
long size = info.getSize();
String url = "/rest/file/" + key; 
FileMeta meta = new FileMeta(name, size, url);

List<FileMeta> meta = Lists.newArrayList(meta);
EntityClass entity= new EntityClass();
entity.setFiles(meta);
return Response.ok(entity).build();
}
```

PS: Additionally, you need to configure POJOMapping in your web.xml.

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: Let me know in case you are stuck or I have missed out on some detail.